# What is the name of this data structure?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

For the structure given in below data model, where each node is,

```
type Person {
       firstName,
       lastName,
       Pointer to list of his children,
       Pointer to next node
 }
```

[image]

---

This data model neither looks like `tree` nor  `graph`.

what is the name of this data model?

Comment: Given that it's a family tree, why wouldn't one think that it looks like a graph?  What if you simplified the links instead and just had the connections between each node?

Comment: @Makoto If the links are not simplified and as it is, what is the name of this data model?

Comment: type definition is self explanatory, it is a tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tree in the [left-child right-sibling representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-child_right-sibling_binary_tree).

A multi-child tree basically needs a dynamic data structure within each node to represent the children. Sometimes, fixed-size nodes are preferred for various reasons. This representation allows doing so in a fixed amount of space per node - the first child only is recorded, and all the children form a linked list. Obviously, searching the children of a node in this representation, is linear in the number of children.

Comment: 1) Can I call it as <b>left-child right-sibling n-ary tree</b>? I read wiki. What is the advantage in showing as "left-child right-sibling" representation instead of "n-ary" tree representation? Any advantage in terms of read/write performance?

Comment: @overexchange No, not really. It is marginally useful when memory is extremely scarce and dynamic allocations are a problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015525/what-is-the-left-child-right-sibling-representation-of-a-tree-why-would-you-us) too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Directed acyclic graph to me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph